# function connection() on null when use database

Tags: laravel, lumen

i'm new on lumen , i start a lumen project with some table. but when I want get some table use this code

```
Course::all();
```

lumen said Call to a member function connection() on null

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 3245:
Call to a member function connection() on null
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in lumen by default Eloquent is off , you should enable that.

for that you should write this code on your app.php in bootstrap folder

```
$app->withEloquent()
```